# Holomorphicity of piecewise function (excluding a compact set)

Tags: complex-analysis

The context is that I am trying to construct a holomorphic map with certain properties.

$f(x,y,z,w)=\begin{cases}
xw-yz & \text{ if } (x,y,z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^4\setminus{S^3}\\ 
 0& \text{ if } (x,y,z,w)\in S^3 
\end{cases}$

The function above has the properties that I want, but it seems far away from been holomorphic, but I am not quite sure (mostly because I want it to be). Can someone quickly verify that it's not ?

Comment: Maybe there is a general case of Hartogs' theorem or something similar that makes the map holomorphic, I know some weird stuff happening in multivariable complex functions etc. Or maybe it's really simple that is not holomorphic and i am missing it out.

Comment: How is $S^3$ embedded in $C^4$? Is it the unit sphere in the $xy$-coordinate plane $C^2$? The answer really depends on the embedding.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I didn't even think of that. What i mean is $^3=\{(x,y,z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^4 |^2+^2+^2+^2=1\}$.

Comment: Hint: Your function is not even continuous. And what compact are you talking about in the title? Your "complexified sphere" $S^3$ is not compact.

Comment: @MoisheKohan you said it depends on the embedding, so can it be holomorphic?

Comment: @MoisheKohan what if i take the double origin point with the 4 variables, does it change anything?

Comment: It can be, if $S^3$ meant to be a sphere in the $xy$-plane, but you stated that it is not.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this means. In any case, if you want to modify your question you should do so by editing the post.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean  the set defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=0$ but thank you.

Comment: @MoisheKohan also what do you mean by the sphere in xy-plane ?

Comment: xy-plane in your notation would be complex 2-dimensional subspace given by the equations $z=w=0$. The sphere in this subspace is given by the usual equation $|x|^2+|y|^2=1$, where $x,y$ are complex coordinates.